# mysql return 2 row if field value is 2

Tags: mysql, select

I have a simple lable printing web page, but ran into a snag where if someone orders 2 books.

sql

```
SELECT 
    contacts.name,contacts.address,contacts_extra.amount_books
FROM contact 
INNER JOIN contacts_extra ON contacts.id = contacts_extra.cid
WHERE 
    contacts_extra.amount_books >= '1'
```

now if contacts_extra amount_books = 2 then it must return 2 rows for we need 2 labels.

regards

Comment: you sure about: `if someone orders 2 books`. On your query, you have `contacts_extra.amount_books >= '1'` should it be `contacts_extra.amount_books = '2'`?

Comment: What is issue here? show us your records here

Answer (score 0):

Use `Group By` , see below:

```
SELECT contacts.name,contacts.address,contacts_extra.amount_books
FROM contact 
INNER JOIN contacts_extra on contacts.id = contacts_extra.cid
WHERE contacts_extra.amount_books >= '1'
GROUP BY contacts.id;
```

Comment: missing the point - the field value says how many labels. the >= 1 is just not to return entries where value = '0'

Answer (score 0):

Lets simplyfy

```
select id,name,total_copier from contacts.
```

that's the select statement. 
As is it can bring back

```
1,john,1
2,peter,3
3,sara,2
```

I need it to be

```
1,john,1
2,peter,2
2,peter,2
2,peter,2
3,sara,2
3,sara,2
```

the third column decides how many times to return the row.